# MySql Insert Operation Failing

Tags: java, mysql

I am demostrating Java Servlet - MySql Application.

following is my ApplicationDAO method

```
    public int registerUser(User user) {
    
    int rowsAffected = 0;
    
    try {
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnectionToDatabase();
        
        String insertQuery = "insert into users values{?,?,?,?,?,?}";
        
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        
        statement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
        statement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        statement.setString(3, user.getFirstName());
        statement.setString(4, user.getLastName());
        statement.setInt(5, user.getAge());
        statement.setString(6, user.getActivity());
        System.out.println(insertQuery);
        
        rowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate();
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Servlet code:

```
    @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // collect all the data
    String userName = req.getParameter("username");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    String firstName = req.getParameter("fname");
    String lastName = req.getParameter("lname");
    String activity = req.getParameter("activity");
    int age = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("age"));
    
    // fill it up in a user bean
    User user = new User(userName, password, firstName, lastName, age, activity);

    // call DAO layer
    ApplicationDao applicationDao = new ApplicationDao();
    int rows = applicationDao.registerUser(user);
    
    // prepare the information message
    String infoMessage = null;
    if(rows==0) {
        infoMessage = "Sorry, an error occurred";
    }else {
        infoMessage="User was registered succesfully";
    }
```

console:

[image]

error message:

[image]

tried to debug but cannot fix any solution to it, also tried naming columns as  (column1, column2....) in the prepare statement but does not work, Strangly the getProduct method for

select * from products works fine...please help bedug.

Comment: You are using curly braces instead of parentheses in ApplicationDAO : registerUser method and so the error.
Correct it to.
 `String insertQuery = "insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";`

Comment: `{`  `}`     is not same as `(`   `)`

Comment: this resolved the issue, thanks for prompt response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `curly braces` instead of `parentheses` in ApplicationDAO : registerUser method and so the error.

`{ }` is not same as `( )`

Correct it to :

```
String insertQuery = "insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```